# Sideways text block with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a block of text to display sideways in a web page. Here's my starting point, an image and some links:

[image]

The HTML for that looks like this:

```
<div>
  <img src="med.png">

  <span class="links">
    <a href="full.png">[full]</a>
    <a href="tn.png">[tn]</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

What I want is for it to display like this:

[image]

I've tried CSS rotation:

```
.links {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

but I get this:

[image]

OK, I understand that, it's rotating around the center point. I've played around with transform-origin but that just picks a different rotation point. What I really want is for that span to rotate sideways, then sorta slide back into place inline.

Comment: You mean you want to also add a sort of animation?

Answer (score 5):

You could rotate it on the bottom left point with `transform-origin: bottom left;` and move it up with `translateX(-100%);`

```css
.links {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GbPO.png">

  <span class="links">
    <a href="full.png">[full]</a>
    <a href="tn.png">[tn]</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also adjust the [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

```css
.links {
  display: inline-block;
  writing-mode:vertical-rl;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GbPO.png">

  <span class="links">
    <a href="full.png">[full]</a>
    <a href="tn.png">[tn]</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i got it working using absolute positioning and changing your mark-up slightly

CSS

```
.blue {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.outer-div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.links {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: right;
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -7px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 100% 75%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="blue"></div>

  <p class="links">
    <a href="full.png">[full]</a>
    <a href="tn.png">[tn]</a>
  </p>
</div>
```